# Text inside ActiveX textbox 'stretches' with move & size with cells

Tags: excel, vba

On my worksheet there are ActiveX textboxes, which I have sized so they fit the cell they are in.

I have set object positioning to move and size with cells.

When I change the size of the cells, the textboxes resize as intended, but the text inside the box 'stretches' instead of remaining the same.

Comment: I recommend to stay away from ActiveX if possible, they are full of bugs and known to cause odd behavior. Also I don't see any use of a TextBox on a worksheet. Either use UserForms if you want to make a form, or use the cells of the worksheet to enter things.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it was for the purpose of a scrollbox to make cell size uniform. That can only be done with activeX I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you obviously run into one of the numerous ActiveX bugs. I can only recommend to stay far away from ActiveX, as they are well known to cause odd issues and numerous bugs.

As solution I suggest to ask Microsoft to fix the bug and/or in the meanwhile use the following workaround after you resized columns.

---

There is a workaround, that could fix the odd stretch looking bug:

[image]

You just need to resize the TextBox with VBA like `TextBox1.Width = TextBox1.Width` and everything looks smooth again.

[image]

---

To fix all TextBoxes just loop through all of them and reset their width:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FixOddTextBoxesAfterColumnResize()
    Dim obj As OLEObject
    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If obj.progID = "Forms.TextBox.1" Then
            obj.Width = obj.Width
        End If
    Next obj
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Might just stay away from activex.